# Layout out more views than can be displayed in small widget moves the first view off the top

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit

I am very new to SwiftUI and WidgetKit, so this might have an obvious answer.

```
var body: some View {
        VStack() {
           Text("Hello")
           Text("World")
            Text("World")
            Text("World")
            Text("World")
            Text("World")
            Text("World")
            Text("World")
            Text("World")
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
    }
```

With the above body, the first line is pushed off the top of the widget but the desired outcome being that any views beyond what can be displayed are off the bottom, but the view appears to be centred across all of its children.

Without being able to measure anything, how can this be achieved? The real world example being I don't know the height of the children, I don't know the height of the widget window, so I can't use .offset either.

I have tried overlay, and this almost works but again, without being able to measure anything I can't set a correct overlay value, unless I have missed something.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: One solution Ive found is to hardcode the maxHeight to 160, but that won't work on all devices etc. If I could measure the widget size then that is a possible solution...

Answer (score 0):

Try padding
Text("Hello")
.padding(.leading, -7)

Comment: Ah no, the list of views is dynamic, this doesn't come close to solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was related to the maxHeight of the widget, if only there was a way of getting that. And there is!

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/widgetfamily

Long story short I can get the widget size from the context.